# Can V8 perform build-time precompilation of JS code?

Tags: javascript, android, v8, escape-analysis, ahead-of-time-compile

We're trying to optimize for start-up time of JS code on mobile and looking for the opportunities. I've found [Facebook Hermes JS engine](https://hermesengine.dev/) created for a similar purpose but we heavily depend on V8 at the moment.

Can build-time precompilation be done with V8 meaning parsing and code optimization will be done in compile-time and saving some time in runtime? Generating LLVM bitcode from the source code and executing bitcode in runtime seems to be pretty close to what i imagine. WASM seems to be not an option (at least for mobile).

If it's possible, can one provide a simple example of trivial JS code optimized with V8?

PS. Probably it would also help with memory consumption which can be the secondary goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 supports [*heap snapshots*](https://v8.dev/blog/custom-startup-snapshots) for this very purpose. It's [used by the Atom editor](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/how-atom-uses-chromium-snapshots/), for instance, to improve startup time. It's not so much about precompiling as it is about prebuilding your global environment and instantiating your functions (which may not be compiled [yet], just converted to bytecode for [Ignition](https://v8.dev/docs/ignition), which is sufficient). If you're using Electron, the [`mksnapshot` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mksnapshot) may be useful. (And if not, looking at how it works may still be useful.)

I haven't done any V8 hacking, but the [example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/4.5.103.9/test/cctest/test-serialize.cc#661) they link from the [blog post above](https://v8.dev/blog/custom-startup-snapshots) is as follows:

```
TEST(PerIsolateSnapshotBlobs) {
  DisableTurbofan();
  const char* source1 = "function f() { return 42; }";
  const char* source2 =
      "function f() { return g() * 2; }"
      "function g() { return 43; }"
      "/./.test('a')";
  v8::StartupData data1 = v8::V8::CreateSnapshotDataBlob(source1);
  v8::StartupData data2 = v8::V8::CreateSnapshotDataBlob(source2);
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams params1;
  params1.snapshot_blob = &data1;
  params1.array_buffer_allocator = CcTest::array_buffer_allocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate1 = v8::Isolate::New(params1);
  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope i_scope(isolate1);
    v8::HandleScope h_scope(isolate1);
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate1);
    delete[] data1.data;  // We can dispose of the snapshot blob now.
    v8::Context::Scope c_scope(context);
    CHECK_EQ(42, CompileRun("f()")->ToInt32(isolate1)->Int32Value());
    CHECK(CompileRun("this.g")->IsUndefined());
  }
  isolate1->Dispose();
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams params2;
  params2.snapshot_blob = &data2;
  params2.array_buffer_allocator = CcTest::array_buffer_allocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate2 = v8::Isolate::New(params2);
  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope i_scope(isolate2);
    v8::HandleScope h_scope(isolate2);
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate2);
    delete[] data2.data;  // We can dispose of the snapshot blob now.
    v8::Context::Scope c_scope(context);
    CHECK_EQ(86, CompileRun("f()")->ToInt32(isolate2)->Int32Value());
    CHECK_EQ(43, CompileRun("g()")->ToInt32(isolate2)->Int32Value());
  }
  isolate2->Dispose();
}
```

That blog post (and the associated example?) is from 2015 so things have probably moved on since.